# How to Insert Each Dictionary Value into a List After the Corresponding Key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, data-manipulation

I have a list of elements and I'd like to insert dictionary values into that list after the key element:

```
listicle = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
some_new_elements = {'b':'x', 'd':'y'}
```

giving the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y']
```

What is the Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: A 'flat map' list comprehension. See https://coderwall.com/p/rcmaea/flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-one-line-in-python - it shows the "normal" method with iteration and result_list.add and method using list comprehension. Both approaches function here. Both are "Pythonic".

Comment: That is, consider a normal 'map' of `['a', 'b', 'c' ..]` -> `[['a'], ['b','x'], ['c'] ..]`. The 'flat map' of that concatenates all the mapped sequences together. Using two discrete list comprehensions might be a helpful way to start and see the operations support eachother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` which is like a `flatmap`:

```
from itertools import chain
listicle = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
some_new_elements = {'b':'x', 'd':'y'}
output = list(chain.from_iterable([[x, some_new_elements[x]] if x in some_new_elements else [x] for x in listicle]))
print(output) # output:  ['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y']
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way:

```py
import itertools

listicle = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
some_new_elements = {'b':'x', 'd':'y'}

new_map = ([m, some_new_elements[m]] if m in some_new_elements else [m] for m in listicle)
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_map)))
>>> ['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y']
```

A simple way to do that without list comprehension:

```py
listicle = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
some_new_elements = {'b':'x', 'd':'y'}

output = []
for x in listicle:
    output.append(x)
    if(x in some_new_elements):
        output.append(some_new_elements[x])

print(output)
>>>['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y']
```

Comment: @user2864740 thanks, I added more context, but I haven't found the perfect answer.

Comment: The simple map can be generated with `([m,some_new_elements[m]] if m in some_new_elements else [m] for m in listicle)`. This results in a sequence of elements like `['a']` (no match) and `['b','x']` (match). This result can be combined into a 'flat map' or using something like [`itertools.chain/chain_from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) (which is probably more clear anyway) to flatten all the contained lists into a single list.

Comment: I find  your solution without list comprehension much more readable. +1

Comment: Both ways are “correct”. Having both in the answer makes it much stronger. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comprehension to do this:

```
>>> listicle = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> some_new_elements = {'b':'x', 'd':'y'}
>>> sentinel=object()
>>> [x for t in ((e, some_new_elements.get(e, sentinel)) for e in listicle) for x in t if x !=sentinel]
['a', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'y']
```